# How to remove an element from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, element

I have an array named 'a' with the numbers 1 to 10,000 in it. I would like jump through the list in 2s, which I have managed successfully. However, I want the program to remove every second number, like the number '2' for example, which would be assigned to 'x'. I have tried functions such as .pop() but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Please can someone help. Am i just using the function wrong?

```
for x in range(0,9999,2):
    a.pop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a list of the values you *do* want. It is a lot more efficient:

```
a = range(1,10000)

a = a[1::2]     #will contain all the even numbers
```

By the way, the reason your code is not working is because you are (in a sense) modifying your list while iterating through it. You should avoid it thoroughly unless you are *absolutely* sure that that is what you want.

The syntax above uses the `list[start:end:step]` syntax. Therefore, `[1::2]` will get every second element of the list starting at the second element. Similarly, `[::2]` will get every second element of the list starting at the default 1st element since no start index was specified.

Comment: Im new to python could you explain  what the '::' means?

Comment: he is not really modifying his list while iterating over it :)

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgeCarmichael, Answer updated. Hope it helps

Comment: `range(1, 10000, 2)` will create a list with odd numbers.

Comment: He is not even "in a sense" modifying a list while iterating through it.  He is not understanding what `.pop()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension

```
a = [i for i in range(10000) if not i%2]
```